# How to add install option to package in Puppet manifest

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puppet

For the last two days I tried to install just two modules for **Nginx** on a Debian 7 x64 virtual machine, created with **Vagrant**. For now I have this manifest:

```
package { 'nginx':
  ensure => 'present',
  install_options => [ '--with-http_secure_link_module', '--with-http_image_filter_module' ],
}

include '::apt'

apt::source { 'nginx':
  location   => "http://nginx.org/packages/debian",
  repos      => 'nginx',
  key        => '7BD9BF62',
  key_source => 'http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key',
  before     => Package['nginx'],
}

#import 'nodes/*.pp'
```

After I run `vagrant provision`, I get into VM through ssh with `vagrant ssh`, and this is what I see:

```
vagrant@packer-virtualbox-iso:~$ sudo nginx -V

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
built by gcc 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) 
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: 
--prefix=/etc/nginx 
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log  
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid  
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock  
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp  
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp  
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp  
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp  
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp  
--user=nginx
--group=nginx
--with-http_ssl_module
--with-http_realip_module  
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_dav_module  
--with-http_flv_module
--with-http_mp4_module
--with-http_gunzip_module  
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_random_index_module  
--with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_stub_status_module  
--with-http_auth_request_module
--with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module
--with-file-aio
--with-http_spdy_module
--with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed'
--with-ipv6**
```

**image_filter** module had not installed, but **secure_link** is ok ( I think it's ok because it was installed by default).

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're mixing concepts. When installing through `apt`, you cannot pass compile time options. The package contains pre-compiled binaries. Puppet's `package` type is not for compiling software. There might be modules that allow this, but even this appears doubtful.

Comment: @Felix Frank, thank you for attention. Could you tell me the method I can install these modules? I do not care how exactly, I even tried to compile through puppet Exec commands, but I failed, because Puppet told me he can not find **cd** command...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - I know of no such modules, and I doubt that one exists. As for not finding `cd`, you should supply the `path` parameter to the `exec` resource to allow it to find the commands. Don't bother with `cd` at all - specify the `cwd` for the `exec` using the appropriate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix mentioned, the `package` resource in Puppet is not for compiling packages, it's for managing installing and uninstalling packages.

If you want to compile an nginx Debian package specific options or additions, I recommend using [fpm-cookery](https://github.com/bernd/fpm-cookery). There's an [example nginx recipe](https://github.com/bernd/fpm-recipes/blob/master/nginx/recipe.rb) that might be useful for you.